# Unable to pause activity nullpointexeption

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, actionbarsherlock

I have a nullpointexeption, which makes my application unable to pause. (Maybe it's important to note that I work in SherlockActionBar fragments).

I think it's because of this line of code:

```
// SEND THE FILE
String sharePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/Soundboard/Ringtones/custom_ringtone.ogg";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

And here is my log:

```
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.mega.sb/com.mega.sb.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2835)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2813)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:140)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1617)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:481)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:126)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1181)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1219)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2861)
09-16 19:33:57.030: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    ... 12 more
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check your file path you can log to see if any variable is null or not and use `getAbsolutePath()` instead of `getPath()`

```
String sharePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + "/Soundboard/Ringtones/custom_ringtone.ogg";
File f = new File(sharePath);
if(f!=null && f.exists()) {
Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
....

}
```

Comment: My app doesn't crash anymore. But it also doesn't set the file as a ringtone. Besides that, the app crashes when I press the home button. But that worked until I added this line of code

Comment: are you overriding the method `onSaveInstanceState`?

Comment: And if the code doest not set the file as ringtone, check your file path. The file must be there in the given path.

Comment: No, I don't override the onSaveInstanceState

Comment: Will check the file path, thought it was good though! Thanks!